# Google Maps API: Radius circle not drawing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've followed the instruction given on the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple) site, but my circle is never being drawn to my map, and I don't really understand what I am missing, could anybody point me in the right direction?

Here is my method to add the new address marker and search radius to the map (Note that the marker is added as expected):

```
// Add the users point to the map
function addAddress() {

    // Get the users current location
    var location      = document.getElementById("P1_LOCATION").value;  // Users postcode
    var radius_size   = document.getElementById("P1_RADIUS").value;    // Users radius size in miles
    var search_radius;

    // Translate the users location onto the map
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': location}, function(results, status) {
       if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

           // Center around the users location
           map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

           // Place a marker where the user is situated
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
           });

            // configure the radius
            // Construct the radius circle
            var radiusOptions = {
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: map, 
                center: marker.center,     // I want to set the center around the users location
                radius: radius_size        // I want the radius to be in miles, how do I do this?
            };

            // add the radius circle to the map
            search_radius = new google.maps.Circle(radiusOptions); 
       } 
    });
}
```

And I'm sure someone will ask if I have configured a base map object, this is done in my initializer method:

```
var geocoder;
var map;

// Create our base map object 
function initialize()
{
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
   var mapOptions = { 
      zoom: 12,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }   
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
```

How would I go about getting the radius to display around the given point? any suggestiosn would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this error with the posted code: `Uncaught InvalidValueError: setRadius: not a number`
But the real issues was this: `center: marker.center,` should be `center: marker.getPosition(),`  (a [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) doesn't have a "center" property)

working code snippet:

```js
// Add the users point to the map
function addAddress() {

  // Get the users current location
  var location = document.getElementById("P1_LOCATION").value; // Users postcode
  var radius_size = parseFloat(document.getElementById("P1_RADIUS").value); // Users radius size in meters (unless you scale it to miles)
  var search_radius;

  // Translate the users location onto the map
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': location
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      // Center around the users location
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

      // Place a marker where the user is situated
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });

      // configure the radius
      // Construct the radius circle
      var radiusOptions = {
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: marker.getPosition(), // I want to set the center around the users location
        radius: radius_size // I want the radius to be in miles, how do I do this?
      };

      // add the radius circle to the map
      search_radius = new google.maps.Circle(radiusOptions);
    }
  });
}
var geocoder;
var map;

// Create our base map object 
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="P1_LOCATION" value="08646" type="text" />
<input id="P1_RADIUS" value="10000" type="text" />
<input id="geocode" value="geocode" type="button" onclick="addAddress()" />
<div id="map" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I hadn't added the parseInt method, as it was coming back as a string - everything works for me now but will accept your answer as it is definitely more concise than mine.  Thanks for your time man

Answer (score 0):

For anybody in future who encounters the same problem, make sure you take the extra step which is not demonstrated in the API guide, and that is to set the Map which the radius object belongs too, in my case:

```
search_radius.setMap(map);
```

Comment: You set the map property in your code. You _shouldn't_ need to set it again (unless the map is defined after the geocoder returns its result, but you didn't provide enough context to know that)

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip, I thought it was strange when following through the tutorial - I guess its my fault to adding to code I'd already written, very new to the API but was a rookie error on my behalf :)